# Pandas add column using a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
col1 col2 col3
 1    8    6
 2    9    5
 5    3    9
```

Now I want to add a new column with values from a list for each and every row of my dataframe. So if my list is like so:

```
lst = ["a", "b","c"]
```

then I want the final dataframe to be like:

```
col1 col2 col3 name
 1    8    6    a
 1    8    6    b
 1    8    6    c
 2    9    5    a
 2    9    5    b
 2    9    5    c
 5    3    9    a
 5    3    9    b
 5    3    9    c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by length of list and then append new column with [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
lst = ["a", "b","c"]

df1 = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(lst))]
             .assign(name=np.tile(lst, len(df)))
             .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
   col1  col2  col3 name
0     1     8     6    a
1     1     8     6    b
2     1     8     6    c
3     2     9     5    a
4     2     9     5    b
5     2     9     5    c
6     5     3     9    a
7     5     3     9    b
8     5     3     9    c
```

Or use `cross join` with `DataFrame` from `list`:

```
df1 = df.assign(a=1).merge(pd.DataFrame({'name':lst, 'a':1}), on='a').drop('a', axis=1)
print (df1)
   col1  col2  col3 name
0     1     8     6    a
1     1     8     6    b
2     1     8     6    c
3     2     9     5    a
4     2     9     5    b
5     2     9     5    c
6     5     3     9    a
7     5     3     9    b
8     5     3     9    c
```